# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel 7 and PHP 7.4.

I'm working on databases and suddenly stuck over issue when I'm trying to generate a foreign key for user in another table. It should be straight away process and I'm following the doc, still getting error.

> General error: 1005 Can't create table `carchain_qrcode`.`sellers` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

User Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
         });
}
```

Sellers Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sellers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('seller_name');
        $table->string('seller_email');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short**: For quick fix refer to @Aless55 answer. The main thing to keep in mind is that `id` and `foreign_key` column types should match.

**Correct way**:
It is better to use Laravel's built-in APIs for creating `primary key` and `foreign key`. More details here:
It will automatically take care of column types, creating indexes, and so on. In addition, sticking to official documentation makes it easy to understand the code by others, and maintain it by the developer (It is just my opinion).

In your case:

Users table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->id();
       $table->string('name')->unique();
       $table->string('email')->unique();
     });
}
```

Sellers table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sellers', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->id();
       $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained(); // this will automatically detect which table to reference
       $table->string('seller_name');
       $table->string('seller_email');
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. That's a smart answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is that the **id** of your **users** table is **bigInteger** and  not **bigIncrements** or **unsignedBigInteger**. 
In Laravel 7 you can simply do: **$table->id()** to create the id column.

Comment: Bravo!.
"bigIncrements" worked for me. You saved my brain man. 
Thanks

Comment: @shaan im glad it works now, i would really appreciate if you accepted my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

this error occured due to incorrect data type used on the foreign key which you are going to create. The primary key data type on the `users table` should be same as the data type which you used in `Sellers table` as below:

**Users Table**

```
$table->id();
```

**Sellers Table**

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
```

or if you used any other data type on users table primary key then the foreign key in the other table should be same accordingly.